# Install Scrapy on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to install Scrapy on El Capitan but have not been successful yet. This happens when I use `pip install Scrapy`:

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /<scrapy_project>/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/<scrapy_project>/venv/build/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/p6/jvf54l7d5c7dntzm6d3rfc3w0000gn/T/pip-D2QIZq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /<scrapy_project>/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /<scrapy_project>/venv/build/cryptography
```

My Xcode and Xcode command tools are up to date.
I tried installing Scrapy with and without the approach via homebrew according to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install

Edit: I did the following:

- `brew install openssl && brew link openssl --force` according to
  Craicerjack's suggestion
- `pip install cryptography`
- `pip install scrapy`

all worked without any errors. But `scrapy --version` throws this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/<scrapy_project>/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so, 2): Symbol not found: _BIO_new_CMS
  Referenced from: /<scrapy_project>/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /<scrapy_project>/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so
```

Comment: looking at that looks like a problem with building the cryptography package. maybe `pip install cryptography` first? also [the second comment on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215447/error-occurs-when-installing-cryptography-for-scrapy-in-virtualenv-on-os-x) might be of help

Comment: You are missing a dev package for openssl

Comment: @Craicerjack thanks for your comment! please see the edit of my question.

Comment: well this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462779/symbol-not-found-bio-new-cms, seems to have the solution to that.

Comment: Yay! You saved my day. Thank you @Craicerjack! You can post a solution that i would accept if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is with installation of the dependencies needed for Scrapy

first of all you should upgrade to the latest version of pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If that doesnt work, to build cryptography and dynamically link it:

```
brew install openssl
env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography
```

further information on installation can be found in the [cryptography docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-os-x)

Other issues may be solved by using the command

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install cryptography --no-use-wheel
```

This shouldnt be necessary however, if all your software (latest pip and cryptography), is up to date. More on this issue can be found in the issues in the [cryptography repo on github](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2138)